# How do I print a random variable from a set in python

Tags: python-3.x

For my AI ChatBot, I need a function that selects a certain text string from a set of text strings but I cant seem to figure out what to put in for my print function.

Ive tried the random module but I dont know how to use it. Here is the code.

```
Greeting_Reply = {"Hey!", "Hi", "Hi, How are you?", "Hello!"}

while True:
    inp = input("Talk to " + MY_NAME + "\n")
    if inp in Greeting:
        print(?)
```

What do I put in place of the ? in the print function. Thanks.

Comment: You should read the documentation and probably a Python tutorial first, but try `print(random.choice(list(Greeting_Reply)))` for starters.

Comment: Isn't that the same as your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.choice`:

```
random.choice(list(Greeting_Reply))
```

in your call to `print`.

Comment: Thankyou once again. I am not new to python but i have never done this specific stuff before.

Comment: @JaydenCollis, I think you should also change `if inp in Greeting:` to `if inp in Greeting_Reply:`.

Comment: I think ill keep it the same because i have OCD with my bots answers being capitalized while the greetings set have no caps included for quickly typing.

Comment: @Austin There is probably a different variable named `Greeting` which has (unfortunately) not been posted.

Comment: @Selcuk, got it. It was the same variable (I guess) in his previous question. (that's why I just shared a thought).

Comment: @JaydenCollis Please don't forget to accept Austin's answer if it helped.